# How to update to the final version of google glass?

Tags: android, google-glass

I've tried following all the tutorials and put the glasses in fastreboot mode. I have to add more details but I added the pid at the bottom changed the inf file updates the drivers in a Linux Mac and two windows machines

```
    changed the android_winusb.inf 
    ;
    ; Android WinUsb driver installation. 
    ; 
    [Version]
    Signature           = "$Windows NT$"
    Class               = AndroidUsbDeviceClass
    ClassGuid           = {3F966BD9-FA04-4ec5-991C- 
    D326973B5128}
    Provider            = %ProviderName%
    DriverVer           = 08/28/2014,11.0.0000.00000
    CatalogFile.NTx86   = androidwinusb86.cat
    CatalogFile.NTamd64 = androidwinusba64.cat

    [ClassInstall32]
    Addreg = AndroidWinUsbClassReg

    [AndroidWinUsbClassReg]
    HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
    HKR,,Icon,,-1


    [Manufacturer]
    %ProviderName% = Google, NTx86, NTamd64

    [Google.NTx86]
    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, 
    USB\Class_ff&SubClass_42&Prot_01
    %SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, 
    USB\Class_ff&SubClass_42&Prot_03

    [Google.NTamd64]
    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, 
    USB\Class_ff&SubClass_42&Prot_01
    %SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, 
    USB\Class_ff&SubClass_42&Prot_03

    [USB_Install]
    Include = winusb.inf
    Needs   = WINUSB.NT

    [USB_Install.Services]
    Include     = winusb.inf
    AddService  = WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

    [WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
    DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
    ServiceType     = 1
    StartType       = 3
    ErrorControl    = 1
    ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

    [USB_Install.Wdf]
    KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUSB_Install

     [WinUSB_Install]
    KmdfLibraryVersion  = 1.9

    [USB_Install.HW]
    AddReg  = Dev_AddReg

    [Dev_AddReg]
    HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{F72FE0D4-CBCB-407d- 
   8814-9ED673D0DD6B}"

    [USB_Install.CoInstallers]
    AddReg    = CoInstallers_AddReg
    CopyFiles = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

    [CoInstallers_AddReg]
 
 
 
 HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoI 
   nstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

    [CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
    WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
    WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

    [DestinationDirs]
    CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

    [SourceDisksNames]
    1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
    2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

    [SourceDisksFiles.x86]
    WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 1
    WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 1

    [SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
    WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 2
    WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 2

    [Strings]
    ProviderName                = "Google, Inc."
    SingleAdbInterface          = "Android ADB Interface"
    CompositeAdbInterface       = "Android Composite ADB         
    Interface"
    SingleBootLoaderInterface   = "Android Bootloader Interface"
    WinUSB_SvcDesc              = "Android USB Driver"
    DISK_NAME                   = "Android WinUsb installation disk"
    ClassName                   = "Android Device"
```

updated the driver via device manager
and nothing seems to be working! can anyone help please!

I noticed that the pid is 9002 I dont know if that helps

Comment: What tutorials are you following and what is actually going wrong? There's a few different ways to update the EE2 firmware

Comment: so I've used a hand full ranging from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHqhwMPkqR0, https://support.google.com/glass/answer/9649198?hl=en, https://jeffzzq.medium.com/using-google-glass-in-2020-5f0a01188e6e, and I can't find the last one. After putting it into fastboot mode, even when I change the .inf file to add it OR make it universal, when I type fastboot devices, it does not appear, ( I have added the drivers via the .inf file.

Comment: Have you tried something like this for the fastboot-specific device driver? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/fastboot-doesnt-see-device

Stand-alone driver installation might be useful as well. I've not had much luck with the driver in general - Windows seems to 'lose' it and it needs reinstallation occasionally https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb . I recommend use a Linux PC so you don't need to manually install the driver.